# What is the difference between class member collection marked as "virtual" and one without "virtual" keyword

Tags: c#, inheritance

Given the following. What is the difference between having and not have the virtual keyword?

```
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        this.UserTests = new List<UserTest>();
    }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserTest> UserTests { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The `virtual` keyword allows you to override the property in sub-classes

Comment: Have you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx? If so, do you have specific bits you didn't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following `Person` and `Employee` classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string WhoAmI()
    {
        return "I'm just a person and my name is " + this.Name;
    }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string WhoAmI()
    {
        return "I'm an employed person and my name is " + this.Name;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `WhoAmI` method is not marked with `virtual` or `override` in any of the classes. Yet, when you run the following code:

```
Employee p = new Employee { Name = "John Smith" };
p.WhoAmI(); // yields "I'm an employed person and my name is John Smith"
```

But, this code:

```
Person p = new Employee { Name = "John Smith" };
p.WhoAmI(); // yields "I'm just a person and my name is John Smith"
```

The reason for the difference is simple. In the first case you explicitly instructed the compiler to invoke the more specific `WhoAmI` by referring to the `p` variable as an `Employee`, then `Employee.WhoAmI` will be invoked.

In the latter case we refer to `p` as its base class `Person` hence `Person.WhoAmI` was invoked.

### **Polymorphism:**

What if we wanted that even when referring to `p` as `Person` we'll still be able to invoke the more specific implementation?

That's when the `virtual` and `override` come in handy:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string WhoAmI()
    {
        return "I'm just a person and my name is " + this.Name;
    }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public override string WhoAmI()
    {
        return "I'm an employed person and my name is " + this.Name;
    }
}
```

And now it yields the 'correct' results:

```
Person p = new Employee { Name = "John Smith" };
p.WhoAmI(); // yields "I'm an employed person and my name is John Smith"
```

Also, when using a Polymorphic list:

```
var data = new List<Person>();
data.Add(new Person { Name = "Regular Person" });
data.Add(new Employee { Name = "Employed Person" });

foreach (var p in data)
{
     p.WhoAmI(); // will call the 'correct' method
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That means that if some other `class` will derive from your `Test` base `class`, if required, it will be able to *override* the inherited `UserTests` property logic with other logic, for example:

```
    private ICollection<UserTest> _userTests;
    public class ComplexTest : Test
    {
        public override ICollection<UserTest> UserTests
        {
          get { return _userTests.Where(...)} //class-specific logic 
          set { _userTests = value }
        }
    }
```